# Group by ranges having subsequent results of a substring

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having the following data structure:

```
UniqueAssignedNumber   | UniqueEntity

6371170100010001       | a
6371170100010011       | a
6371170100010021       | a
6371170100010031       | b
6371170100010041       | b
6371170100010051       | b
6371170100010061       | a
6371170100010071       | a
```

I need to group by ranges grouping by the substring(UniqueAssignedNumber, 7, 4) and substring(UniqueAssignedNumber, 11, 5)
The problem is as you can see these ranges are not subsequent.

This is the best result I came up with:

```
select
substring(t.numero, 7, 4) as a, 
min(substring(t.numero, 11, 5)) as rangefrom,
max(substring(t.numero, 11, 5)) as rangeto,
entity


from table t
where substring(t.numero, 0, 7) = '637117'
group by (substring(t.numero, 7, 4))
```

But I get the following result:

```
0100    53001   54000   CLUB IN CAPITAL
0100    77806   78000   CLUB IN LA PLATA
0100    08663   99999   CLUB IN MAR DEL PLATA
0100    43001   80000   CLUB IN MENDOZA
0100    78001   78999   CLUB IN MONTE
```

And I need multiple ranges.

Like this:

```
0100    53001   54000   CLUB IN CAPITAL
0100    77806   78000   CLUB IN LA PLATA
0100    08663   99999   CLUB IN MAR DEL PLATA
0100    43001   44000   CLUB IN MENDOZA
0100    77000   78000   CLUB IN MENDOZA
0100    79000   80000   CLUB IN MENDOZA
0100    78001   78999   CLUB IN MONTE
```

Comment: 0100    08663   99999   CLUB IN MAR DEL PLATA seems to break the "rule" to end at the next 1000 number...  e.g.  53001..54000   Is MarDelPlata special in some way or should it be  08663..09000 ?

Comment: There is no pattern, the client can assign 574 numbers to an entity, and then the following 426 to another entity, and then 1300 numbers to the first entity. I would need to log the three of this ranges. I know it is screwed up, and I fixed it for future number generations so the client can keep track of these ranges. I'm still trying to figure this out for all the previous records.

Answer (score 0):

Another problem is presented when the expected results are sorted, revealing column rangeto overlaps with "77000   78000   CLUB IN MENDOZA" and "77806   78000   CLUB IN LA PLATA" where each of them end in 78000.

Does the column "UniqueEntity" contain the Club names?  If not, then where do they come from, another joined table?

```
0100    08663   99999   CLUB IN MAR DEL PLATA
0100    43001   44000   CLUB IN MENDOZA
0100    53001   54000   CLUB IN CAPITAL
0100    77000   78000   CLUB IN MENDOZA
0100    77806   78000   CLUB IN LA PLATA
0100    78001   78999   CLUB IN MONTE
0100    79000   80000   CLUB IN MENDOZA
```

Thur Feb 21, 2019 21:30 - Here is some SQL that will work, depending on what the DDL of tables is.  Change my [StackOver].[dbo].[GroupByRanges] to your own table.

```
--SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT 
     substring(t.numero, 1, 7) as ClubArea
    ,substring(t.numero, 8, 4)  as ClubGroup
    ,substring(t.numero, 12, 5) as ClubSeq
    ,t.entity
    From [StackOver].[dbo].[GroupByRanges] as t
    Where substring(t.numero, 1, 7) = '6371170'
    Order By t.numero

OPEN cur

Declare @minClubSeq NVARCHAR(255), @maxClubSeq NVARCHAR(255), @nextClubSeq NVARCHAR(255), @prevEntity NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @returnTable TABLE (rminClubSeq NVARCHAR(255), rmaxClubSeq NVARCHAR(255), rnextClubSeq NVARCHAR(255),  rEntity NVARCHAR(255))
SET @prevEntity = ''
DECLARE @skip  NVARCHAR(255), @ClubSeq NVARCHAR(255),  @entity NVARCHAR(255)

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @skip, @skip, @ClubSeq, @entity
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    If ( (@prevEntity <> @entity) ) 
        BEGIN
            Insert INTO @returnTable Select @minClubSeq, @maxClubSeq, @ClubSeq,  @prevEntity
            Set @prevEntity = @entity
            Set @minClubSeq = @ClubSeq
        END
    Set @maxClubSeq = @ClubSeq
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @skip, @skip, @ClubSeq, @entity 
END
        Insert INTO @returnTable Select @minClubSeq, @maxClubSeq, @ClubSeq,  @prevEntity

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur


Select * From @returnTable Where rEntity > ''
```

Comment: I'm joining an external table of these entities

Comment: Please show corrected SQL that joins for UniqueEntity.  We really want to separate the expected results by their specific Clubs.  What is the function of UniqueEntity?

Comment: @monkjuice see added SQL for you to use.